# Uibuttong not changing image after selection in 64 bit ipad retina?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

`UIButton` changing its image in 32-bit iPad but not changing it's image after selection in 64-bit iPad retina(used high resolution images only).Can you please provide me some information regarding this?

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"active.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Have you added `inactive@2x.png` and `active@2x.png`?

Comment: i used three uibuttons.one uibutton out of three is changing it's image after selecting(same images used for all three uibuttons).other two uibuttons not changing its image?

Comment: Try without the file extension `[UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive"]` and `[UIImage imageNamed:@"active"]` so iOS looks for a PNG by default and also sets the scale property correctly. And check the images are named correctly.

Comment: thanks for ur reply.I tried what you mentioned.but still the same result.images names are correct

Comment: @SaharaPune try it with "UIControlStateNormal" for both Butons. and try to control it with a Bool variable, that whether its Clicked or not.

Comment: You mentioned in your comment on the answer below that you are using tap gesture on top of `UIButton`. What do you want to achieve by doing that? Defeats the purpose of using a `UIButton`. Try removing the tap gesture, and use `addTarget:action:`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. Inside the button action method put

```
- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [sender setSelected:!sender.selected];
}
```

Comment: i used tapgesture recogniser for uibutton.All uibutton actions are working correctly.Only one thing is not working i.e.uibutton is not changing its image after selection.

Comment: why you are un necessarily using tap gesture for button?

Comment: i have to use single tap and double tap on uibutton in my app?

Comment: Did you try `[sender setSelected:!sender.selected]` on tap gesture target method

Comment: instead of sender you can use button outlet like [self.button setSelected:!self.button.selected]